# Sending TLS messages with out encryption using openssl code

Tags: encryption, tls, openssl

Is it possible to send messages over TLS with out encryption?

If so which cipher suite is needed for this?

Comment: Do you mean cipher suite `NONE`?

Comment: Are you wanting authentication but not confidentiality? Or neither?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Just to save the CPU time for the encryption?

Comment: want to check whther that suite is supported by the server or not..

Comment: @Kalai: If you're looking to test your setup's ssl security, you can use the [Qualys SSL Labs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are a number of TLS cipher suites that don't include any encryption.  These cipher suites are not normally used by OpenSSL, but they can be explicitly requested e.g. using the `-cipher` option to the OpenSSL tools.

Specifically, the suites offering no encryption and/or authetication are found under the `NULL` and `aNULL` cipher classes.  The [`openssl ciphers` manual page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html) describes them as:

> "**eNULL, NULL**:
>   the "NULL" ciphers that is those offering no encryption. Because these offer no encryption at all and are a security risk they are disabled unless explicitly included.
>
> **aNULL**:
>   the cipher suites offering no authentication. This is currently the anonymous DH algorithms. These cipher suites are vulnerable to a "man in the middle" attack and so their use is normally discouraged."

To get a list of the cipher suites included in the `NULL` class, run `openssl ciphers -v NULL`.  For me, the returned list looks like this:

```
ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
AECDH-NULL-SHA          SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-NULL-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-NULL-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
NULL-SHA256             TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
NULL-SHA                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
NULL-MD5                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=MD5
```

To see if a specific server lets you connect to it using one of these suites, run:

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port -cipher NULL
```

Of course, for most services, this should cause the cipher suite negotiation to fail, like this:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -cipher NULL
CONNECTED(00000003)
3073382600:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert
handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:724:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 139 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```